# LLamada a funcion PHP desde Javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript, php, funciones

Les agradecería mucho me ayuden con el siguiente inconveniente.
El código siguiente funciona. Pero al cambiar esta linea no me funciona:

```
var result = "<?php php_func(10); ?>";     // Si funciona, 10 es el Primary Key

var result = "<?php php_func(" + document._form1.txt_busca_pk.value + "); ?>";     // No funciona, en el document._form1.txt_busca_pk.value escribo el Primary Key a consultar
```

Esta parte

```
"<?php php_func(" + document._form1.txt_busca_pk.value + "); ?>";
```

la he probado de muchas maneras, y con ninguna me funciona. Les agradezco su ayuda. Adjunto el código que está en un solo archivo.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function clickMe()
            {
                //var result = "<?php php_func(10); ?>";   Si funciona
                var result = "<?php php_func("+document._form1.txt_busca_pk.value+"); ?>";   // No funciona
                document._form1.txt_nombre_mostrar.value = result;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="clickMe()"> Click </button> <br>
        
        <form name="_form1" id="_form1">
            <input name = "txt_busca_pk" type = "text" value = "10">     <!-- Primary Key del registro a mosrtrar -->
            <input name = "txt_nombre_mostrar" type = "text" value = ""> <!-- Dónde muestro el resultado de la consulta -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    function php_func($Param01)
    {
        $Resu = "";
        $bdd_enlace_1 = mysqli_connect("192.....", "usuario", "clave", "base");
        $fila_1 = mysqli_query($bdd_enlace_1, "select * from externos where AutNum = $Param01;");
        
        while ($campos_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fila_1))
        {
            $Resu = $campos_1[3];
        }
        
        mysqli_close($bdd_enlace_1);
        echo $Resu;
    }
?>
```

Comment: El PHP se interpreta en el servidor, es decir, antes de mostrar la página y de que pueda actuar el javascript, que se ejecuta en el navegador del cliente, por lo tanto todo eso no te funcionará de ese modo que lo estás intentando. Debes plantearte el uso de ajax para pasarle datos de javascript al PHP, pero eso implica un cambio de método que poco tiene que ver con el actual, que repito, no te va a funcionar así.

Comment: Listo. Comprendido.